# Laravel 5.7: Should the "remember" cookie get deleted when logging out?

Tags: laravel, cryptography

I have a custom `LoginController` etc. So in my test, when logging a user out, the user's `remember`-cookie is left untouched.

I am basically using the same logout code as provided in the default `LoginController`:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

And then in my test I check if the cookie is missing. This is the assertion that fails:
`$response->assertCookieMissing(Auth::guard()->getRecallerName());`

> Should the "remember" cookie get deleted when logging out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, while it could clean up the cookie, Laravel doesn't and doesn't need to.

You could look into the logout method of your guard, likely SessionGuard::logout, to see how Laravel handles it:  Laravel regenerates the remember token on logout, so it will no longer match, so even if the token stays on the client, it's no longer of any use.